# Create dataframe as list of dict column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:
[image]

And I want to generate other dataframe like this:

[image]

Where sku are the list of codes of products column, combined with "code" column (1, 2, 3, 4). I developed this code, but I want to do this in a short or better way:

```
skus_with_layoutSegments = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['sku','code'])
for i in range(len(segments_telynet)):
  skus = pd.DataFrame(segments_telynet.loc[i,'products']).rename(columns={'code': 'sku'})
  skus['code'] = int(segments_telynet.loc[i,'code'])
  skus_with_layoutSegments = skus_with_layoutSegments.append(skus).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Can anyone help me with a better solution, I want to avoid doing a for loop.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
out = df.explode('products')
out['products'] = out['products'].str.get('code')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to better illustrate this solution I reproduced part of your dataframe:

```
list1 = [{'Code':'ALBN100043'}, {'Code':'ALBN100044'}, {'Code':'ALBN100045'}, {'Code':'ALBN100046'}, {'Code':'ALBN100047'}, {'Code':'HOG900035'}, {'Code':'HOG900036'}, {'Code':'HOG900037'}]
list2 = [{'Code':'ALBN100043'}, {'Code':'ALBN100044'}, {'Code':'ALBN100045'}, {'Code':'ALBN100046'}, {'Code':'ALBN100047'}, {'Code':'HOG900035'}, {'Code':'HOG900036'}, {'Code':'HOG900037'}]
list3 = [{'Code':'3462456'}, {'Code':'23453'}, {'Code':'74573475'}, {'Code':'34535'}, {'Code':'2452'}, {'Code':'174564'}, {'Code':'865785'}, {'Code':'34535'}, {'Code':'3543743'},]

df = pd.DataFrame({'code'    :[1,2,3],
                   'dateIni' :['20200101','20200101','20200101'],
                   'dateEnd' :['99992131','99992131','99992131'],
                   'products':[list1,list2,list3]})
df

    code     dateIni     dateEnd    products
0      1    20200101    99992131    [{'Code': 'ALBN100043'}, {'Code': 'ALBN100044'...
1      2    20200101    99992131    [{'Code': 'ALBN100043'}, {'Code': 'ALBN100044'...
2      3    20200101    99992131    [{'Code': '3462456'}, {'Code': '23453'}, {'Cod...
```

The first part is just like @Mayank's answer:

```
out = df.explode('products')
```

Output:

```
out

 code    dateIni     dateEnd                  products
0   1   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100043'}
0   1   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100044'}
0   1   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100045'}
0   1   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100046'}
0   1   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100047'}
0   1   20200101    99992131     {'Code': 'HOG900035'}
0   1   20200101    99992131     {'Code': 'HOG900036'}
0   1   20200101    99992131     {'Code': 'HOG900037'}
1   2   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100043'}
1   2   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100044'}
1   2   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100045'}
1   2   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100046'}
1   2   20200101    99992131    {'Code': 'ALBN100047'}
1   2   20200101    99992131     {'Code': 'HOG900035'}
1   2   20200101    99992131     {'Code': 'HOG900036'}
1   2   20200101    99992131     {'Code': 'HOG900037'}
2   3   20200101    99992131       {'Code': '3462456'}
2   3   20200101    99992131         {'Code': '23453'}
2   3   20200101    99992131      {'Code': '74573475'}
2   3   20200101    99992131         {'Code': '34535'}
2   3   20200101    99992131          {'Code': '2452'}
2   3   20200101    99992131        {'Code': '174564'}
2   3   20200101    99992131        {'Code': '865785'}
2   3   20200101    99992131         {'Code': '34535'}
2   3   20200101    99992131       {'Code': '3543743'}
```

Now we differ:

```
out['products'] = out['products'].apply(lambda x: x.get('Code'))
```

Output:

```
 code    dateIni     dateEnd      products
0   1   20200101    99992131    ALBN100043
0   1   20200101    99992131    ALBN100044
0   1   20200101    99992131    ALBN100045
0   1   20200101    99992131    ALBN100046
0   1   20200101    99992131    ALBN100047
0   1   20200101    99992131     HOG900035
0   1   20200101    99992131     HOG900036
0   1   20200101    99992131     HOG900037
1   2   20200101    99992131    ALBN100043
1   2   20200101    99992131    ALBN100044
1   2   20200101    99992131    ALBN100045
1   2   20200101    99992131    ALBN100046
1   2   20200101    99992131    ALBN100047
1   2   20200101    99992131     HOG900035
1   2   20200101    99992131     HOG900036
1   2   20200101    99992131     HOG900037
2   3   20200101    99992131       3462456
2   3   20200101    99992131         23453
2   3   20200101    99992131      74573475
2   3   20200101    99992131         34535
2   3   20200101    99992131          2452
2   3   20200101    99992131        174564
2   3   20200101    99992131        865785
2   3   20200101    99992131         34535
2   3   20200101    99992131       3543743
```